# Javascript - How to access a word in this array of array of strings?

Tags: javascript, arrays

```
var phrase1 = [];
phrase1.push({word: "I", x:50, y:50});
phrase1.push({word: "like", x:70, y:50});
phrase1.push({word: "you", x:120, y:50});

var phrase2 = [];
phrase2.push({word: "Well", x:50, y:50});
phrase2.push({word: "I", x:110, y:50});
phrase2.push({word: "tried", x:130, y:50});
phrase2.push({word: "to", x:190, y:50});

var phrase3 = [];
phrase3.push({word: "Hey", x:40, y:50});
phrase3.push({word: "where", x:100, y:50});
phrase3.push({word: "you", x:180, y:50});
phrase3.push({word: "at", x:220, y:50});

var phrases = {"like" : phrase1,
             "tried" : phrase2,
             "where" : phrase3
             };
```

This is a snippet of the code I received. I'm having trouble figuring out how to access a word from the `phrases` array. Let's say I want to access the word "like" from `phrase1`, through `phrases`, what is the correct syntax to do so?

Tried so many combinations that I'm just stumped now. If someone could point me to the right direction, that would be great. Thank you!

I can access individual phrases with

```
phrase1[1].word
```

But unable to find a way to get it through `phrases`.

Comment: `phrases.like[1].word` if the arrays are always going to be static. Otherwise you'd have to iterate it and do some checking.

Comment: `phrases` is not an array, it is a JavaScript object.

Answer (score 1):

**phrases** isn't an array, it is an object.

You can access the properties using dot notation, like this:

```
phrases.like[0].word
```

You can also use bracket notation, as follows:

```
phrases["like"][0].word
```

Comment: Thank you! Got confused for a second. If my phrases keyword was a string, let say it was "like you" instead of "like". How would that work considering that there's a space in the string?

Comment: If there are spaces in the property name, you would have to use bracket notation, with quotes.

Answer (score 0):

To access `phrases` as an array, it needs to be an array (you have it as an object):

```
phrases=[phrase1, phrase2, phrase3];
```

Then:

```
phrases[0][1].word;
```

works.